# React this.props not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am in the process of learning React and trying a sample code from a book. The code is simple it is supposed to display vowels in different colors defined in the ReactDOM.render but instead it displays them all in one color coming from the style tag.

Attached below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset-="utf-8'">
    <title>Styling in React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #container {
            padding: 50px;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

        div div div {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #ffde00;
            color: #333;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 32px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");
class Letter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var letterStyle =  {
    padding:10,
    margin:10,
    backgroundColor:this.props.bgcolor,
    color:"#333",
    display:"inline-block",
    fontFamily:"monospace",
    fontSize:32,
    textAlign:"center"
        };
        return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
              );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        <Letter bgcolor="#58B3FF">A</Letter>
        <Letter bgcolor="#FF605F">E</Letter>
        <Letter bgcolor="#FFD52E">I</Letter>
        <Letter bgcolor="#49DD8E">O</Letter>
        <Letter bgcolor="#AE99FF">U</Letter>
        </div>,
        destination
           );
        </script>
</body>

</html>
}
```

Comment: You define the `letterStyle` variable, but you never use it... It should probably be added to the `<div style={letterStyle}>{this.props.children}</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using letterStyle anywhere.  Try the following:

```
render() {
  var letterStyle =  {
    padding:10,
    margin:10,
    backgroundColor:this.props.bgcolor,
    color:"#333",
    display:"inline-block",
    fontFamily:"monospace",
    fontSize:32,
    textAlign:"center"
  };
  return (
    <div style={letterStyle}>
       {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try {this.props.bgcolor} you need a {} to use dynamic variables.

Comment: I have tried that already gives me error
babel.min.js:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script:

Comment: I think this advice is incorrect because he isn't using `this.props.bgcolor` within a JSX block. The place where he is using `this.props.bgcolor` is in pure JavaScript.

Comment: @ jaredkwright - Thanks for the comment about NOT using a '{}' to access component properties without JSX syntax. It fixed my problem at least. So, '${this.props.myProp}' was not getting expanded in my non JSX environment. Once I updated that to 'this.props.myProp;. it started getting recognized and was being expanded as expected.